# for all integers $a$ and $b$, if $a \equiv 2 (\text{mod}\,4)$ and $b$ is odd, then $ab \equiv2 (\text{mod}\,4)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Is False? Since $2 \equiv 2\,(\text{mod}\,4)$ and $2 \times 3 = 6\,$ then $\,6 ≠ 2$.

This is a proof by counter-example?

It seemed too easy.

That's wrong.

So;

a ≡ 2 (mod 4) = 4q + 2 and b = 2q + 1

ab = (4q + 2)(2q + 1) = 8q + 2q + 2q + 2

then ab = 16q + 2 which is 2 mod 16

Comment: @Behrouz Maleki: You should use "$\equiv$", not "$=$".

Answer (score 3):

$6\neq2$ is correct, but the task is not saying that $ab$ will **equal** $2$, it says that it will have the remainder of $2$ when divided by $4$, and since $6=1\cdot 4 + 2$, you have $$6\equiv 2 \mod 4$$

so no, your counterexample is not correct.

---

**Hint 1**:

The statement is not false

**Hint 2**:

Fill in the gaps:

- If $a\equiv 2\mod 4$, then it can be written as $\_\cdot \_ + \_$
- If $b$ is odd, then it can be written as $\_\cdot\_ +\_$
- Then $ab$ is eqal to $\_\_\_$

Comment: I get ab = 16q + 2 which is 2 mod 16

Comment: @SunshineTS Wrong result. If you edit your question to show me how you reached that result, I can also tell you what you did wrong. Currently, I can only guess.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so. a ≡ 2 mod 4 can be written as 4 q + 2 and b = 2 q + 1 then ab = 16 q + 2 which is 2 mod 16.... basically.

Comment: @SunshineTS Correct (I mean that last statement. The entire answer is still wrong)